# challenge with decimal point in float type

Tags: string, rounding

I have some files and I want to open them and read some data. the files name have a sequence: 769.999 779.999 789.999 ... 
I wrote the below code for opening the files and it works until the file name is 999.999.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
string fn, path_str;
string root("/home/mostafa/OpenFOAM/mostafa-2.1.0/run/tutorials/incompressible/pisoFoam/channelLES/Balaras/09/postProcessing/mydata/");
string endfile("/Data0_U_UMean.xy");

int main()
{
    float fileName;
    std::cout.precision(7);
    for (int t=0;t<95;t++)
    {
        float mydata[210]={0};

        fileName=769.999+t*10.000000;
        cout << fileName << endl;
        string fn = static_cast<ostringstream*>( &(ostringstream() << fileName) )->str();

        //string fn = std::to_string(fileName);
        path_str=root+ fn+endfile;
        const char* path=path_str.c_str();
        cout << path << endl;
        //myfile.open (path,ios::out);


        ifstream myfile(path, fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::binary);

        if (!myfile)
        {
            cout << "Cannot open file.\n";
            return 0;
        }
        for (int x=0; x<210; x++)
        {
            myfile >> mydata[x];
            //cout << mydata[x] << "\t";
        }
        myfile.close();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

then for file name 1009.999 it says that there's not such file and actually it rounds the number to 1010.

my questions is how  can I prevent this rounding?

Regards,
Mostafa

Comment: File names are strings, not `float`s. You must use string manipulation, not floating-point multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to set precision to your **ostringstream**. For example replace your

```
ostringstream() << fileName
```

to

```
ostringstream() << std::setprecision(7) << fileName;
```